# How to generate kubeconfig user for a service-account?

Tags: python, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, service-accounts

**I'm stuck at creating a `user` for my `serivice_account` which I can use in my kubeconfig**

**Background**:
I have a cluser-A, which I have created using the [google-cloud-python](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python) library. I can see the cluster created in the console. Now I want to deploy some manifests to this cluster so i'm trying to use the [kubernetes-python](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python) client. To create a `Client()` object, I need to have a KUBECONFIG so I can:

```
client = kubernetes.client.load_kube_config(<MY_KUBE_CONFIG>)
```

I'm stuck at generating a `user` for this service_account in my kubeconfig. I don't know what kind of authentication certificate/key I should use for my [user](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/configure-access-multiple-clusters/#define-clusters-users-and-contexts).

Searched everywhere but still can't figure out how to use my service_account to access my GKE cluster through the kubernetes-python library.

**Additional Info**:
I already have a `Credentials()` object ([source](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/google.auth.credentials.html#google.auth.credentials.Credentials)) created using the `service_accounts.Credentails()` class ([source](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/google.oauth2.service_account.html#google.oauth2.service_account.Credentials)).

Answer (score 2):

A Kubernetes ServiceAccount is generally used by a service within the cluster itself, and most clients offer a version of [`rest.InClusterConfig()`](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/blob/master/rest/config.go#L433-L439). If you mean a GCP-level service account, it is activated as below:

```
gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file gcp-key.json
```

and then probably you would set a project and use `gcloud container clusters get-credentials` as per normal with GKE to get Kubernetes config and credentials.